# Screen reader(Narrator) not reading the button text on chrome browser

Tags: button, roles, wai-aria, screen-readers, narrator

I have question regarding screen reader (windows narrator) in chrome browser.

I have a button tag that will get focus on tab key press. I am expecting a screen reader to read what button it is but it says "no item in view" when it focused.

I have added role="button" but it wasn't helping me out and also i changed to input element() still no luck.

This is my HTML code for that page.

```
<button class="k-primary k-button bold applicant-form-cancel-button" role="button" aria-label="Cancel"
                        id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
```

Any comments on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but it does not seem to be an issue anymore. On Windows 10 Version 22H2 the above button element reads "Cancel Button" on Windows Narrator (default settings).